# How to run a rmarkdown to create multiple html with different parameters?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a code in R, which is done in rMarkdown, it needs to run several times but with different parameter values.

How can I solve it? I have put an example of simplified problems.

Suppose I need to print different values in a loops, in order to make it simple I used simple loops.

For each combination of these two loops I want to make one html file, for example means 200 *400 different html report files.

````
---
title: "file1"
author: "user"
date: "25 1 2021"
output: html_document
---

# The first loop should be done, from 1:100, 101:200 ... to ...   20001:20100
  ```{r}
  i=getfirst()
  j=getsecond()
  ```

```{r}

for (i in i:j) print(i)
```

# The second loop should be done, from 1:50, 51:100  ... to ...  20001:20050
```{r}
for (i in i-50:j-50) print(i)
```
````

suppose each time we may have different i and j which should pass into markdown file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply create a wrapper script (i.e. a separate e.g. `.R`) file, where you specify:

## R file

```r
for (i in 1:10){
  j = i+50
  if(!dir.exists(paste0("directory_",i))){dir.create(paste0("directory_",i))}
  knitr::knit(input = "markdown.Rmd",output = paste0("directory_",i,"/output",i,"_",j,".html"))
}
```

And then your Rmd file, which you have saved as `markdown.Rmd` in this example looks like this:

## RMarkdown file

````
---
title: "file1"
author: "user"
date: "25 1 2021"
output: html_document
---

# The first loop should be done, from 1:100, 101:200 ... to ... 20001:20100

```{r}
for (i in i:j) print(i)
```

# The second loop should be done, from 1:50, 51:100 ... to ... 20001:20050

```{r}
for (i in i-50:j-50) print(i)
```
````

Comment: thanks, how can I pass parameter to markdown file?

Comment: When you execute the `knit` command, it uses your working directory as well - so the `run_chunk` variable is automatically passed to the markdown file. 
So this should work and result in two different html files with different output.

Comment: please take a look at my new code, suppose each time I may have different parameter, I need to store e.g. 100s different html files.

Comment: Ok, now I've modified the R file to just create a simple loop over some `i` values. The `j` here is just a standard `i + 50` but you can wrap another `j` loop around it if you like. Does that work now?

Comment: yes, it works, how can I put each html in a separated directory then??

Comment: No problem, you simply change the `output` option in `knit`. Currently it gives each html file a new name (so here you get 10 files in one directory)
I have modified the code above so that it creates a new directory (if it does not yet exist) for each `i` and the stores the file in it (with the `i` and `j` in the name). You can of course play around with the `paste0` function to determine whether each `i` is in a separate folder!
If that's what you were looking for, always grateful for an upvote and accepting the answer :)

Comment: Yes, but in my real code I have produce 15 csv files, which should be stored in individual directory, I mean each html and their csv should be in one directory.

Comment: The I recommend saving the path to both the csv and the html as a variable and then using that variable when saving. If the csv file is already in that folder, then you can find out the path dynamically using `list.files` - if you want to save it, then you can copy the `paste0` command for a `write_csv` command or something. I'm afraid it's a bit difficult for me to understand your exact workflow apart from the above...

Answer (score 1):

There is [a dedicated chapter in the official documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html), "Knitting with parameters", that outlines how to proceed in your use-case.